# page.set('content') doesn't work with dynamic content in phantomjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I tried to use phantomjs for screen capturing my page with [node-phantom](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom) bridge. Here is what I'm trying:

```
 var phantom = require('node-phantom');

 phantom.create(function (err, ph) {
            return ph.createPage(function (err, page) {
              return page.set('content', '<html><head></head><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>', function (err, status) {
                  return page.render('./content.png', function (err) {
                    ph.exit();
                  });
                });
            });
          });
```

That works fine, but if I try to set content which contains javascript, that doesn't work. Please help me, why does it not work?

**EDIT:** This doesn't work:

```
var phantom = require('node-phantom');

phantom.create(function (err, ph) {
   return ph.createPage(function (err, page) {
      page.open("about:blank", function(err,status) {
         page.evaluate(function() {        
            document.write('<html><head></head><body><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script><script>$(function(){document.write("Hello from jQuery")})</script></body>');
         });

         setTimeout(function () {
            return page.render('./content.png', function (err) {
                ph.exit();
             }); 
         }, 5000);   
    });         
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript code needs some time to execute. Try to have a delay between setting the page content and calling `render`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why set content does not work, It seems to be a limitation of the phantomjs api. You can just use document.write.

```
var phantom = require('node-phantom');

phantom.create(function (err, ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function (err, page) {
    page.open("about:blank", function(err,status) {
      page.evaluate(function() {        
        document.write('<html><body><script>document.write("<h1>Hello From JS</h1>");</script><p>Hello from html</p></body></html>');
      });
      return page.render('./content.png', function (err) {
        ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });         
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. page.evaluate don't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

as ariya mentioned, time is needed. there is likely an 'onLoadFinished' event for this library (there is for the node lib i use). you can handle this without an arbitrary wait time by seeing my example at the bottom of this github issue: https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/issues/68

```
Document.prototype.captureScreenshot = function(next) {
console.log(">> Rendering screencap for " + this.id)
var self = this;
phantom.create(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.setContent(self.html);
        page.set("viewportSize", {
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080
        });
        page.set('onLoadFinished', function(success) {
            var outputFile = './screenshots/screenshot-' + self.id + '.png';
            page.render(outputFile);
            ph.exit();
            console.log(">> Render complete for " + self.id)
            if (next)
                next(outputFile);
        })
    });
});
```

}