# page.open() function doesn't work properly for some URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, phantomjs

I am new in node. I have written a code using Node and Phantom to scrape a website. My code is working for google.com but not working for facebook because it is internally making an ajax request to other files to get the data.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function(ph) {
   return ph.createPage(function(page) {
       return page.open("https://facebook.com/", function(status) {
            if(status !== 'success'){
                console.log('Unable to load the url!');
                ph.exit();
            } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    return page.evaluate(function() {
                        return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;

                     }, function(result) {
                         console.log(result); //Log out the data.
                         ph.exit();
                     });
                }, 5000);
            };
        });
    });
});
```

So basically when I am executing my code then in case of facebook it is returning *unable to load* but but in case of google it is giving body response.

Can anybody tell me what changes should I do to get the result?

PhantomJS version: 1.9.0

Comment: Sorry @ArtjomB. That was my fault.

Comment: It is version 1.9.0.

Comment: Actually I want to get the whole HTML that means after some times few js files are executed too and make requests to the server and then whole HTML is rendered. I want that HTML but in this case I am not getting that.. I am getting first rendered element and Js file for the second ones. Is it possible to make code in that way?? @Atjom B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass some commandline options to PhantomJS to not use SSLv3 but only TLSv1 and optionally ignore SSL errors (`--web-security=false` might also be helpful):

```
phantom.create('--ssl-protocol=tlsv1', '--ignore-ssl-errors=true', function(ph) {
    ...
```

The reason this might be an issue is that many sites have removed SSLv3 support because of the Poodle vulnerability.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26417660/1816580) provides the solution for plain PhantomJS. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26419531/1816580) elaborates on that issue in more detail for CasperJS.